# Creating Dynamic Modal popups with information from job

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a PHP loop that renders results from a Database:

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $result){
$job_numb = $result['job_numb'];
$job_name = $result['job_name'];
$comments = $result['comments'];
?>
   <tr>
        <td><?php echo "$job_numb";?> </td>
        <td><?php echo "$job_name";?></td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Comments-<?php echo $job_numb;?>">Comments</button>

 <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="Comments-<?php echo $job_numb;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Comments for <?php echo "$job_name" . "$job_numb";?></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <?php echo "$job_name";?>
    <?php echo "$comments";?>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

 </div>
 </div>
      </td>
      <td><a href="path-to-an-editfile/edit.php">Edit Record</a></td>
            </tr>
 <?php
     }
 ?>
```

The Data target for the modal cannot be a STATIC ID because then it's repeating IDs on the same page - so you will just repeat the same information as the first instance of the ID.

What I am after is to make sure the ID is always different for as many records as there are. I have seen the code before, but I cannot find it now. What am I missing?

Comment: Try and put your modal outside of your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a unique ID using `<?php echo` and a unique ID:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Comments-<?php echo $job_numb;?>">Comments</button>

     <div id="Comments-<?php echo $job_numb;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Comments for <?php echo "$job_name" . "&nbsp;|&nbsp;" . "$job_numb";?></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo "$comments";?>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this, I was able to pass all of that dynamic row's specific data to the modal without ID conflicts. I hope this is useful to others seeking out the answer.